# Superfish Menu not fading in

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

I've set up Superfish with my wordpress menu. I have managed to get it working fine. However I have followed the documentation here:

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

Though for some reason the menu just isn't fading in like the example shown.

My url is here:

http://dev.rootshift.com/5peaks/

As you can see when you hover over one of the menu items, the transition just isn't as smooth as the example.

I've made sure to include all the correct files and such.

My js is the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sf-menu').superfish();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you include the [superfish css](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/css/superfish.css) file? There is the transition on the background enabled so that you get that fading effect.

Comment: I did include the superfish css file, but I still don't have the animation, odd...

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the [jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.

Download it and implement the following code next to your Javascript calls:

```
  <script type="text/javacript="{jsFolder}/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js">
  </script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've added that, but it hasn't actually fixed the problem.